# In Google Sheets how do I enter the plus sign at the start of a field value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating a spreadsheet where one column must hold phone numbers.
Some phone numbers have the plus sign at the beginning of the string.

However, Attempting to enter a '+' at the start of a field activates a feature of Google Sheets.

How do I turn this feature off and get fields to just accept alphanumeric strings?

Answer (score 11):

You should use an "escape" character: '

This way:

```
    '+1234
```

Comment: This works. However, it's a pain to do this when repeatedly copying and pasting. Is there a way to get the field to just accept the pasted value?

Comment: You may also format the cell as text (and not as formula) before you enter your text into.

Answer (score 3):

you can add it as text string like:

```
="+99 555 653"
```